# How to open a bootstrap model from dynamic dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to open a bootstrap model from a bootstrap list item.

Here is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
         //Attach click event to your Dropdownlist
         $("#ddl_product").change(function () {
            //Get the selected valu of dropdownlist
            selection = $(this).val();
            //If its one then show the dialog window. You can change this condition as per your need
            if (selection == 0) {
               //Show the modal window
               $('#myModal').modal('show');
            }
         });
    });
    </script>
```

**My drop down list:**

```
     <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_product" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_product_SelectedIndexChanged">
     </asp:DropDownList>
```

**My model:**

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" runat="server">
         <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 67%; height: auto;">
             <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                       <h4 class="modal-title">New Product</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="hide_scroll">
                           <iframe scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="Product.aspx/#companyform" style="height: 790px; width:1120px;"></iframe>
                       </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
             </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

**My .cs file:**

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        ListItem newproduct = new ListItem("New Product", 0.ToString());
        ddl_product.Items.Add(newproduct);
        DM.DropdownFill("select * from Product", ddl_product, "product_Name", "Id");
    }
    protected void ddl_product_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ddl_product.SelectedItem.Value== "0")
        {
            // Response.Write("Show model");
            myModal.Visible = true;
         }
     }
```

Here the model is not visible on the "New Product" selection from drop down.

Comment: can you show us html with list "New Product"  which you are clicking?

Comment: i added list "New Product" from the code side, not from the html side.  ListItem newproduct = new ListItem("New Product", 0.ToString());
        ddl_product.Items.Add(newproduct);
        DM.DropdownFill("select * from Product", ddl_product, "product_Name", "Id");

Comment: Yes but you run the code and open that page in browser? And on page there where a list/dropdown or?

Comment: Did you try by adding attribute class and style dynamically? e.g. myModal.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block"); myModal.Attributes.Add("class", "modal fade in");

Comment: Now it is running successful by adding myModal.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block"); myModal.Attributes.Add("class", "modal fade in");                                  Thank you!!